# How to add emoji in a pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, emoji

How can I add emoji in a dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

list_emoji_found = {
 ':)': 12248,
 ':0': 88724,
 ':jabber:': 692,
 '8)': 719,
 ':-)': 351
}

#convert to series
s = pd.Series(list_emoji_found);
#convert to DataFrame
s = pd.DataFrame({'emoji':s.index, 'count':s.values})
s
```

Returns:

[image]

```
import emoji # Needs 'pip install emoji'

s['icons'] = s['emoji'].apply(lambda x: emoji.emojize(x))
```

Returns:

[image]

My expected result should have the third column (icons) with the emoji representation of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are using non-existent emojis. There is no `':)'` or `:jabber:` emojis. You can find "official" emojis [here](https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/).
2. You should use `use_aliases=True` in your lambdas. Here is the example:

```
import pandas as pd

list_emoji_found = {
 ':)': 12248,
 ':heart:': 88724,
 ':relaxed:': 692,
 ':gun:': 719,
 ':-)': 351
}

s = pd.Series(list_emoji_found);
s = pd.DataFrame({'emoji':s.index, 'count':s.values})
s['icons'] = s['emoji'].apply(lambda x: emoji.emojize(x, use_aliases=True))
s
```

It will return:

```
    emoji       count   icons
0   :)          12248   :)
1   :heart:     88724   ❤
2   :relaxed:   692     ☺
3   :gun:       719     
4   :-)         351     :-)
```

Comment: in the second to last line, where is `emoji.` (in the lambda func)  came from ?